# Ajax recibir datos desde PHP con Json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Quiero recibir los datos que envie desde un archivo php a ajax, para escribirlo en consola, pero no me llega nada, no se que hacer

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];

$conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=fhernandez;host=localhost","postgres","monotono11",$options);

$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM region');
$resultado_region= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($resultado_region);


?>
```

Y el siguiente es el archivo JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var nombre;
    var cod_region;
    var select_region = $("#region");
    $.ajax({
        url: "llenar_combo.php",
        dataType:"json",
        succes: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
        


    });



})
```

Sinceramente me he basado en paginas y videos, pero todos lo hacen de manera distinta pero no hacen lo que necesito , practicamente estoy al intento y error pero ya no se que mas hacer.

No entiendo por que no me llega el resultado, lo envio por JSON , y ajax segun los videos, deberia recibirlo, si alguien me puede ayudar a por que no se me muestra en consola y la logica de lo que estoy haciendo muchas gracias

Comment: la  idea es recibir el JSON y llenar con ajax un combox pero ni escribir en consola puedo

Comment: no sale nada, sale en blanco, pero cuando hago un echo en el php me sale la array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considera las siguientes observaciones:

- Para el caso específico de tu *petición ajax*, ocurre que estás declarando mal el método, debería quedar de esta forma:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "llenar_combo.php",
      dataType:"json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
  })
  ```

Donde como notas:

- El método `done`<sup>1</sup> se encadena al final del objeto de la petición
- Por otro lado si usas alguna versión inferior a **JQuery 3** entonces puedes optar por sustituir a `.done(.....)` por `.success(..............)`

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Peticiones AJAX en JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)